# Hexeditted shared library 'Version x.so not found' error

Tags: linux, hex, shared-libraries, elf, dlopen

My library A is dependant on external library B. When I use ld on A.so, I see B is linked as B.so.10, yet on my computer the links are:

B.so -> B.so.10

B.so.10 -> B.so.10.5

Im trying to make A link to JUST B.so and use symbolic links for what version to load. I hexeditted A.so and replaced all findings of B.so.10 with B.so, and ld links it just fine, but when I try to dlopen A.so, it says: 'Error loading A.so: Version B.so not found' I've read about symbol versioning and such, but honestly have no clue where to look for what would be causing the issue?

Ive checked readelf and compared a non editted version to mine and I see nothing in the diffs besides the SO name. Elfedit also did not work snd just turned the binary into garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `readelf -V B.so`, you will likely discover that it doesn't *define* version `B.so`, but does define version `B.so.10`.

By replacing all `B.so.10` strings with `B.so` you state to the runtime loader that `A.so` depends on version `B.so` instead of `B.so.10` that it used to depend on.

Since not such version exists at runtime, loader correctly complains.

> Ive checked readelf and compared a non editted version to mine and I see nothing in the diffs besides the SO name.

Check again. In particular, do this:

```
diff <(readelf -V A.so.orig) <(readelf -V A.so)
```

You *should*  see some differences there.

> Im trying to make A link to JUST B.so and use symbolic links for what version to load.

You appear to have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *really* trying to achieve?

**Update:**

> The initial problem is im trying to make my software CUDA version agnostic. ...  I can't take this binary and plop it on another system with a different cufft version as cufft links to a specific version even though the ABI hasn't changed in forever.

Ah, you *do* in fact have an XY problem.

You *can not* in fact deduce that the *ABI* has not changed, unless you verify that *every* structure potentially used in that *ABI* has not changed (this is different from verifying that the *API* has not changed, and you likely did that).

If you succeed in patching out the version, the end result will likely be a mystery crash on a system with different version of CUFFT.

If you are lucky, the crash will happen quickly and reproducibly. If you are unlucky, it will happen rarely and will look completely mysterious and unrelated, will happen only on some systems, only on some customer machines, only after you make totally unrelated changes to your library, etc. etc.

TL;DR: You are setting yourself up for significant pain. Just don't do it.

Comment: I will look into this in the morning and see how it goes, thank you! The initial problem is im trying to make my software CUDA version agnostic. To be able to drop it on any system and run. The library in particular that causes issues is libcufft from the cuda libraries. I can't take this binary and plop it on another system with a different cufft version as cufft links to a specific version even though the ABI hasn't changed in forever.

Comment: If the soversion changed (or one of its dependencies' soversion changed) it's very unlikely that its ABI hasn't changed.

It's not just the ABI you see directly, but it can be any change in the structure that you're allocating.